# Selecting posts where category is like multiple category IDs using REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, regexp-like

I have a string of `category IDs` that look like this `1;2;3;4;`.

Now I want to fetch all the posts that contain each of these variables in the `category` column of the `posts` table.

The `category` column also have the content like this `1;2;3;` depending on what categories have been attached to the post.

How can I set up a `PDO query` that checks if any of the value from the primary string is found within the `category` column in the post table?

I am looking for something which would look like `category LIKE = IN (2;3;4;)`, also it has to work with double/triple ... digits like this: `2;44;23;`.

**Example:**

- Post 1: 1;2;
- Post 2: 3;
- Post 3: 1;

I use the string `1;` to fetch from the post table, and the result I want back is `Post 1` and `Post 3` because they both contain `1;`.

Comment: Is refactoring your table structure an option? Storing delimited lists in fields should (almost) always be avoided.

Comment: It is possible, but what is usually faster? Two separate queries or one query using REGEXP? Im trying to avoid using to many tables.

Comment: REGEXP and LIKE are some of the slowest operators, better to JOIN the related tables in one query.

Comment: How would you write the JOIN in this case to avoid double JOINS?

Comment: What do you mean by double joins? Getting the same post multiple times if it matches multiple categories?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option is to refactor the table into a `posts` table (without the categories list field), and `posts_categories` table (with post_id, and category_id fields).

Then use a simple query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM posts_categories AS pc
INNER JOIN posts AS p ON pc.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE pc.category_id IN ([your list of values])
;
```

Unfortunately, most database libraries do not support arbitrary lists of parameters, so you may need to generate the exact series of `?,?,?,...` in code; but I am unfamiliar with pdo and am only marginally acquainted with php.

Edit: Tweaked query to only show data from posts, and only once per post.

---

If you want the list of categories as well....

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
     , GROUP_CONCAT(assoc_pc.category_id SEPARATOR ';') AS catList
FROM posts_categories AS filtering_pc
INNER JOIN posts AS p ON filtering_pc.post_id = p.post_id
INNER JOIN posts_categories AS assoc_pc ON p.post_id = assoc_pc.post_id
WHERE filtering_pc.category_id IN ([your list of values])
GROUP BY p.post_id
;
```

`GROUP_CONCAT` is MySQL specific; if you want a bit more platform independence, you may want to `SELECT p.*, assoc_pc.caetgory_id` and just `ORDER BY p.post_id` and build the catList in code when processing the ungrouped results.

*Edit: fixed typo, incorrect alias, in second query example.*

Comment: I had a problem with this query. Is there a way for me to fetch ALL posts if no category string is given?

Comment: Not with the same query; you can take out the `WHERE` completely, 'post_categories AS filtering_pc INNER JOIN` and the corresponding `ON filtering_oc.post_id = p.post_id` to get a result that looks like the original table. ....and I noticed a typo in the join condition I pointed out, fixing above now.

Comment: I came across a weird problem, and I haven't been able to verify it yet... It seems like the result is being doubled in my query. Is this somehow incorrect? `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(n.news_id) FROM news_attributes na INNER JOIN news n ON na.attribute_news = n.news_id LEFT JOIN languages l ON n.news_lang = l.language_id WHERE ((l.language_val = :language) OR (n.news_lang_all IS NOT NULL)) AND n.news_deleted IS NULL AND n.news_published = 1";`

Comment: @GjertIngarGjersund not sure how that relates to this one, but I am guessing you want `COUNT(DISTINCT n.news_id)` as `DISTINCT COUNT(n.news_id)` makes little sense without a `GROUP BY` (_and even when it does make sense, is still a very unlikely intent_).